# Define VectorDrawable in XML using Android Studio 0.8.13

Tags: android, vector, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to define a [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) in XML using the <vector> tag introduced in Android 5.0 Lollipop.

I've tried creating an xml file under drawable-v21 res folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:viewportWidth="32"
    android:viewportHeight="32">

    <path
        android:name="icon"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M31 28h-1.59l-.55-.55c1.96-2.27 3.14-5.22 3.14-8.45 0-7.18-5.82-13-13-13s-13 5.82-13 13 5.82 13 13 13c3.23 0 6.18-1.18 8.45-3.13l.55.55v1.58l10 9.98 2.98-2.98-9.98-10zm-12 0c-4.97 0-9-4.03-9-9s4.03-9 9-9 9 4.03 9 9-4.03 9-9 9z"/>

</vector>
```

But the IDE states that "Element vector must be declared".

I've updated the project to target API 21 and updated the SDK to all available tools, SDK and repositories.

What I'm missing?
Thank you!

Comment: search for "andorid", note: its not my typo

Comment: Is that your entire XML file? You are missing a closing tag, for one.

Comment: Sorry, in both cases are typos in the question! I'll correct it immediately! Anyway, the issue persist...

Comment: what issue? with IDE saying "Element vector must be declared" ?

Comment: Both: first the IDE (while editing the file) marks the <vector> tag in red and warns "Element vector must be declared";
Then, when building, gradle fails on aapt returning "Error:(11) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix".

Comment: then change the prefix: from andorid to android

Comment: That's right, now aapt is ok, but the IDE still seems to not recognize the <vector> tag... maybe it's just Android Studio that needs to be updated.

Comment: I updated the question removing the aapt error and leaving the Android Studio warning. Thanks @pskink!

Comment: if its just a warning you can live with that till the new studio realease...

Comment: Yes, indeed... but it cause the code auto completion to be unavailable and some other features to fail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Studio; the editor support for the new Lollipop APIs was not integrated yet; it will appear in Android Studio 0.8.14. (The relevant CL is this one: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/111245)

Comment: Android Studio 0.8.14 Has been released and this issue is fixed as expected.